# Direct access to element of STL list with a pointer

Tags: c++, stl

Is it possible to access an element of an STL linked list directly by it's pointer? My program requires quick insertion, removal and access of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

STL containers use iterators instead of pointers. If you have an iterator that points to an element of your linked list, you can access element's data through it, insert at the iterator's position using the list's [insert method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/insert/), and delete at iterator's position using the [erase method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/erase/).

Comment: Would it be possible to "synthesize" an iterator and use that as the function's perameter?

Comment: @blacklemon67: almost guaranteed you're steeped to far into a broken train of thought. Back out a bit, and design your program with an iterator-based interface to containers, and there is almost surely going to be a neat solution.

Comment: @blacklemon67: why synthesize one when you can just have a real iterator?

Comment: @blacklemon67 you don't need to synthesize it: the container conveniently defines it for you. The type is list<T>::iterator or list<T>::const_iterator if read-only access is sufficient. Take a look at examples in the reference pages that I linked for the way the iterators are used: they are very similar to pointers.

Comment: @blacklemon67, the iterator is designed to act exactly as a pointer would. There's no reason to prefer a pointer to an iterator. You can generate a pointer from the iterator at any time with `&(*iter)`. Unfortunately you can't go the other way around.

Comment: isn't there an advantage to accessing an element directly using a pointer? you can only create an iterator at the beginning or end of a list (which would make erasing linear in time), whereas if you could somehow acess the element using its pointer directly, you could erase it in constant time. This is at least what I thought the OP was getting at.

Comment: @Paul When your container is such that it could give you an iterator to its middle without navigation, e.g. a `vector`, you can get a direct iterator in O(1) by what amounts to pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, you're right. but then the question remains why we can't do this with a list? One might naively assume that if you have a pointer to an element in the list, you could simply derefence it to return that element along with access to the next and previous element, which is enough to delete it in O(1).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using STL linked list, you may want to define your own linked list implementation using pointers. For example:

```
template <class E>
struct Node {
    E data;
    Node * next;
};
```

So define a Node class that will be an element in the linked list. As Kerrek SB suggested, redesigning the program with iterators in mind might be quicker and better in the long term.